# How can I drop packets using RateLimiter?

Tags: java, rate-limiting

I'm trying to use [RateLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) to drop packets at a specific limit per second.

```
final RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(5000.0); // rate = 5000 permits per second
void submitPacket(byte[] packet) {
    rateLimiter.acquire(packet.length);
    networkService.send(packet);
}
```

The problem is that rateLimiter.acquire blocks instead of dropping the packet.  How can I configure rateLimiter to drop my packets if the required bandwidth isn't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RateLimiter.tryAcquire`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html#tryAcquire()) doesn't block, instead returning `false` if the permits aren't immediately available.  You'd probably just write something like

```
if (rateLimiter.tryAcquire(packet.length)) {
   networkService.send(packet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I should have read the API closer!